# Importing Databases into MAMP on a Mac

Tags: mysql, macos

The hard drive on my Mac is failing, so I installed Mavericks on an external hard drive and am setting up my websites there. I also upgraded to `MAMP 3.0`.

Anyway, I copied all my databases from my original hard drive to:

```
Applications > MAMP > db > MySQL
```

But when I open up `phpMyAdmin` in my browser, the only databases that display are the ones that came preinstalled with `MAMP`. Do I have to create all my databases from scratch, or is there a simple way of importing them?

Note: When I look at the icons of my database folders in `Finder`, all the sites I pasted in except two have dark blue bars on their icons. I don't have a clue what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done straight copies like you describe, but your path seems odd:

```
Applications > MAMP > db > MySQL
```

Is that the full path? Shouldn’t that `MySQL` be `mysql`?

Comment: Yikes, you're right about the path. It turns out there are TWO MAMP database folders, one in the applications folder (along with htdocs), the other @ Library > Application Support > Appsolute, or something like that. Anyway, I've got it straightened out now. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Dump your databases using `mysqldump`:

```
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html
```

And if you don't like commandline Workbench is available:

```
http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/
```

Then just restore your databases on new server.